# How to change the icons based on condition with asc and desc from components using angular7

Tags: angular

I am using template binding using ngFor from component to html, here initially i want the sorting icon to be the one which is shown. When I click on the Agent code header, the asc and desc event trigerrers. So if i from component file it is asc then i need only the up arrow and if it is desc then I need only the down arrow, so that if asc, then up arrow shows, if desc down  arrow shows.

I have tried with but didnt worked for me, I am not getting where I am going wrong, could you help me to solve this.

*template*

```
<i class="{{field.icon}}" (click)="(field.param === 'agentCode') && sortAgentList() && sorting==='asc'?"("field.icon === fas fa-sort-up")":("field.icon === fas fa-sort-up")""
                                            aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

component

```
  public sortAgentList() {
    this.sorting = (this.sorting === 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';

  }
```

I had put up working demo as well, please check

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-idh3uk?file=src%2Findex.html)

Comment: @pascalpuetz need help from answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change the icon in your sorting function like this:

```
this.sorting = (this.sorting === 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';

// Change the arrow direction
this.agentListDetails = this.agentListDetails.map(agentListDetail => 
  agentListDetail.param === 'agentCode' 
    ? {
      ...agentListDetail,
      icon: [
        ...agentListDetail.icon.split(' ').filter(i => i !== 'fa-sort' && i !== 'fa-sort-up' && i !== 'fa-sort-down'),
        this.sorting === 'asc' ? 'fa-sort-down' : 'fa-sort-up'
      ].join(' ')
    } : agentListDetail
);
```

Here the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rychzd).

Comment: need help based on this answer

Comment: @pascalupuetz could you please help me to solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60224991/change-icons-based-on-asc-and-dsc-and-retain-other-column-icons-to-default-asc-i