# Change icons based on asc and dsc and retain other column icons to default asc icon which is not active using angular8

Tags: javascript, html, angular

i have dynamically binded the icons for sorting the columns, here if i click on other column for sorting previous column icon remains in the state which i had clicked for, but i want that icon to be in default state except the currently sorted column, and here to sort for the new column i want, it must be clicked 2 times to get it the way i want to sort and the current sorted must be highlighted. I have done upto this and struck. Please help

DEMO:
[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hhj2px?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

TS:

```
 public sortAgentList(param) {
      this.sorting = (this.sorting === 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';

      // Change the arrow direction
      this.agentListDetails = this.agentListDetails.map(agentListDetail =>
        agentListDetail.param === param ? {
          ...agentListDetail, icon:
            [...agentListDetail.icon.split(' ').filter(i => i !== 'fa-sort' && i !== 'fa-sort-up' && i !== 'fa-sort-down'),
            this.sorting === 'asc' ? 'fa-sort-up' : 'fa-sort-down'].join(' ')
        } : agentListDetail
      );
     this.getMethod()
  }
```

Comment: It's a little hard to untangle what's going on here. In your position, I'd be inclined to first switch to a more conventional, template-based approach, rather than programatically setting icon classes. You can write both up and down sort icon elements in the template and use ```*ngIf```s to toggle between them. Or just use the [Angular Material table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) which already supports sorting.

Comment: @Adam Dunkerley Thanks for the response, I am not supposed to use anything other than bootstrap 4, plugins also not allowed to use, so I used this approach. Do I get any solution based on this?? Here the template also goes dynamically so that’s the issue,

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hhj2px

Comment: @MilanRaval thanks for response, sorry it is not working as i wanted, here if i click on one sort icon, and when i click on 2nd header, then only second header must have icon change and other headers must come back to sort-up only

Comment: That was incorrect stackblitz, try this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ebcwwd

Comment: @MilanRaval thanks for response, this really worked, can you please post this as answer

Comment: @MilanRaval, if you get time, please have a look at this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60231853/how-to-throw-validation-message-when-the-form-is-dirty-and-trying-to-click-on-ot

Comment: @MilanRaval can you please help me to solve this , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62913176/how-to-make-icon-change-only-for-particular-table-instead-of-changing-as-whole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have set icon style for each detail in a foreach loop: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ebcwwd